# Selenium C# - How to identify the window after close de modal?

Tags: c#, selenium, modal-dialog

After close the modal window, how to go back to the previus page? 
I need to run a comand, but isn't identify my currente page.

Comment: You are trying to navigate back to a parent window?  If you are, get the window handle for it (again, the parent window) then navigate back to it, using ‘SwitchTo()’.  Also, it would help to show your code.

Comment: I have tried the code

// After Close the modal window
string windowHandle = driver.CurrentWindowHandle;
            driver.SwitchTo().Window(windowHandle);

// To execute
driver.FindElement(By.Id("btnInformacoesContato")).Click();

Comment: That code won’t get the window handle for the main window though.  You have to get that BEFORE you open the modal.

Comment: I have tried to get before, but not works. Errors:
Test method EstruturaTest.BeijaFlor.Participante threw exception: 
OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Element <p class="informacao-opcional" id="btnInformacoesContato">...</p> is not clickable at point (773, 698). Other element would receive the click: <div class="modal fade" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="gridSystemModalLabel" id="cds-consulta-modal" style="display: block;">...</div>
  (Session info: chrome=68.0.3440.106)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following solution to go back to the previous page after closing the modal window (works with Coordinates, for example):

```
IJavaScriptExecutor js = driver as IJavaScriptExecutor;
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
js.ExecuteScript("window.scrollBy(0,950)");
```